# Android Manifest merger confusion regarding tool:replace

Tags: android

Please find below an excerpt from Manifest Merger docs from android.

> tools:node=”replace” Replace the lower priority declaration with the
>   annotated one.

Now I have a library with an XXX theme and an App with theme YYY. While compiling YYY I get the error due to merging and solution suggested is to replace the theme.

I would like to know between my library and app, which is low priority? Also what is going to happen when I use tool:replace in my app manifest for theme replacement? i.e. in short who replaces whom?

Answer (score 1):

The library's manifest is lower priority than the app's manifest. This is based on this page here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#merge_priorities

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `tools:replace` to the theme of your app, then this will override the library's theme XXX with YYY. 
If you try to add the `tools:replace` to your library's theme, this will not have provoke an error, but will not have any effect either, meaning, it does not *enforce* the XXX theme.

I think the reason is, that the library gets compiled first and its manifest is merged "into" the app's manifest, so the *direction* of merging is defined hence.

As I understand merging priorities, they refer to build variants, ABIs and so on rather than app/library relations.